# Prevent user from selecting the highlighted item by enter key (combobox)

Tags: extjs4, ext.net

Actually, I'm trying to use a combo-box in Ext.Net to select a value from its selecting list. This combo-box is editable and user can type any value he want.
On selecting list, I want to prevent user from selecting the highlighted item by pressing Enter key and let him just select it by mouse click. for this, i tried to use an listener on bound list "ItemKeyDown" but it did nothing. Other events related to mouse par example, working fine but all events related to key are not working.
I don't know if i have missed something in configurations or what.
Anyone can give me any advise to make theses listeners work? 
Thanks in advance,

```
var combo = Html.X().ComboBox().DisplayField(mark).ValueField(type).Editable(true)
                    .ID(combo_id).EnableKeyEvents(true).AutoSelect(false).SelectOnFocus(true)
                    .QueryMode(DataLoadMode.Local).ValidateOnBlur(false).ValidateOnChange(false)
                    .ListcConfig(Html.X().BoundList()
                               .Listeners(l => l.ItemKeyDown.Handler = "console.log('ItemKeyDown');")); /// ItemKeyDown not displayed in console.
```

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want the user from selecting by pressing the enter key?

Comment: I just noticed that console is spelled with a capital C in your handler. Could it be that you're trying to use a console that doesn't exist because of case sensitivity? and that is why you are not seeing it logged?

Comment: I verified my code, i just badly typed it here. I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the solution i got from **Ext.Net support team** so if someone need it in future:

```
@(Html.X().ComboBox()
.Listeners(events => {
    events.Expand.Handler = @"this.listKeyNav.map.removeBinding({
                                  key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER
                              });";
    events.Expand.Delay = 1;
    events.Expand.Single = true;
})
```

)

Comment: Here is a [link to the related Ext.NET forum thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?28176-CLOSED-Bound-list-listeners&p=125616&viewfull=1#post125616) for references.